# Get and Select the ListBoxItem clicked from ListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ListBox that slides its ScrollViewer horizontally by dragging with the left mouse button pressed.

```
private ScrollViewer scrollViewer;
private Point scrollMousePoint = new Point();
private double horizontalOffset = 1;

private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Border border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myListBox, 0);
    scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);
    // This works
}

private void myListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    scrollMousePoint = e.GetPosition(scrollViewer);
    horizontalOffset = scrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
    scrollViewer.CaptureMouse();
    // This works
}

private void myListBox_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (scrollViewer.IsMouseCaptured)
        scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(horizontalOffset + (scrollMousePoint.X - e.GetPosition(scrollViewer).X));
    // This works
}

private void myListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    scrollViewer.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    
    if (scrollMousePoint == Mouse.GetPosition(scrollViewer))
    {
        // Click
        // Here I want to get and select the ListBoxItem that was pressed.
    }
}
```

I want to get and select the ListBoxItem that was clicked.

To determine if it is a click without movement, I compare if the position saved in the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and in PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp events are the same.

Comment: Isn't that the selecteditem?

Comment: The CaptureMouse in the myListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event is blocking the selection of the ListBoxItem

Comment: I would try deferring the capturemouse then. Dispatcher.invokeasync that part.

Comment: I can't find a way to detect if the click was without dragging, deferring the CaptureMouse

Comment: Have you tried flagging for mouse button held down instead of capturemouse? Set true on mouse down and false mouse up. Check the flag in mousemove.

Comment: I wonder if you making it difficult for nothing? You don't need to have the scroll viewer to capture mouse input. What is the purpose? You are just tracking the mouse position. This works without mouse capturing.

Comment: @BionicCode 
I use the CaptureMouse to horizontally slide the ListBox holding it down with the left mouse button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
        private void myListBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            scrollViewer.ReleaseMouseCapture();

            if (scrollMousePoint == Mouse.GetPosition(scrollViewer))
            {
                ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;
                if (listBox != null)
                {
                    var element = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(listBox, scrollMousePoint).VisualHit;
                    if (element.GetType() != typeof(ScrollViewer))
                    {
                        while (element.GetType() != typeof(ListBoxItem))
                            element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);

                        (element as ListBoxItem).IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```